# Eclipse java - Different code templates for different source folders

Tags: java, eclipse, templates, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-2018-12

Is there a way to set up different "generated code templates" (to be clear, not the completion templates that come up when you press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>, but instead the ones accessed at `Window -> Preferences` uner `Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates`) for different source folders in an Eclipse project? If it isn't a built-in feature, is there a plugin that can do this?

Meaning, that when I create a file in one source folder, it will use one code template, and when I create another file in a different folder, it will use a different code template.

I am hoping to use this for contest programming, where I have one project for all my contests, and a source folder for each individual contest. Since different contests have different input formats, I would like different source folders to have their own "new file" templates.

I am using the latest Eclipse 2018-12, if it matters.

Comment: Note: 2018-12 hasn't actually been released yet, only release candidates are available at the moment. There may still be more bug fixes before the final release.

Comment: There is no support for this. You could use a separate workspace for each contest.